# Calcular Quantile por categoría en R

Tags: r, rstudio

Necesito identificar por quantil  de las variables ing_cor y tenencia_desc por sus distintas opciones: rentada, propia,etc y graficarla.
Pero no se como realizar el quantile por medio de estas variables que se encuentran en el data set "viviendas_concentradohogar" que tiene 74647 filas pero no logró  realizar este ejercicio.

```
       Ejercicio_quantile <- as.integer(runif(min=0, max=100,n= 74647))
      Quantile2 <-quantile(viviendas_concentradohogar$ing_cor ,na.rm = T)
    
    
    v2<-viviendas_concentradohogar %>% merge(Quantile2) %>% 
                                  rename(Quantile_perteneciente =y)
    plot(Ejercicio_quantile,type="h")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido Carlos a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 2):

Entiendo que lo que buscas es algo así:

```
aggregate(ing_cor ~ tendencia_des, viviendas_concentradohogar, quantile, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comentarios:

- `aggregate()` agrupa por `tendencia_des` y aplica la función de agregación a `ing_cor`: `ing_cor ~ tendencia_des`
- La agregación aplica a cada grupo la función `quantile`

Tomando como ejemplo `mtcars` podemos calcular los cuantiles de las millas por galón según el número de cilindros:

```
aggregate(mpg ~ cyl, mtcars, quantile, na.rm=TRUE)

  cyl mpg.0% mpg.25% mpg.50% mpg.75% mpg.100%
1   4  21.40   22.80   26.00   30.40    33.90
2   6  17.80   18.65   19.70   21.00    21.40
3   8  10.40   14.40   15.20   16.25    19.20
```

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo Patricio,

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo @PatricioMoracho,  Yo había intendado algo asi ```v3<- viviendas_concentradohogar %>% mutate(quantile_ing_cor = ntile(ing_cor, n = 5),Q_tenencia_des = ntile(tenencia_des, n = 5)) ````
 Pero tu propuesta es ma efectiva, al intentar graficar  me sale el error de tipo de string inesperado , voy agregar a la pregunta el resultado que se obtiene con tu sugerencia y el error al graficarlos en la pregunta para un mejor entendimiento de antemano muchas graciaspor tu apoyo